# os x ruby irb/pry not able to display €

Tags: ruby, macos, readline, rbenv

I'm not able to paste `€` in pry or irb.

I think there is a problem with readline so I tried reinstalling ruby and installing different versions using configure opts.

Libyaml, readline and openssl are installed via brew. Ruby is installed via rbenv.

```
$ brew --prefix readline
/usr/local/opt/readline
```

Installed ruby with:

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl` --with-readline-dir=`brew --prefix readline` --with-libyaml-dir=`brew --prefix libyaml`" rbenv install 2.1.5
```

Terminal: Is working in both terminals (Terminal.app and iTerm2) but not working while I'm in irb.

Any ideas?

EDIT: £ is not working aswell. Instead of £ I get #.

```
raducroitoru@dotix ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin14.0$ otool -L readline.bundle
readline.bundle:
    /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.3.0)
    /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib (compatibility version 13.0.0, current version 13.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$ irb -EUTF-8`. What's the output of `$ locale` in your terminal?

https://github.com/cantab/unicode_titlecase/wiki/Displaying-Unicode-Text-in-irb

Comment: still not working with `irb -EUTF-8`. `locale` output: http://paste.debian.net/hidden/14a808db/ , but I don't think locale is the problem since is working while I'm not in irb and it's also working in `$ node`.

Comment: Ha, looks like locale was the issue. Solved with `export LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"`